# Seperate key:value object into arrays

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I'm making an ionic project on where I got an incoming array made of key:value object like:

[image]

is possible to separate those values in 3 different arrays: date[] speed[] and altitude[]?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. And it's not specific to any of the frameworks you've tagged, just basic JS.

Comment: Can you also post the result array which you think the expected result should be?

Comment: @KamranKhatti the expected result should be like: speed["30", "40",....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have data in this format:

```
const data = [{a: 10, b: 20, c: 30}, {a: 100, b: 200, c: 300}, {a: 1000, b: 2000, c: 3000}];

const a = data.map((d) => {
 return d.a
});
const b = data.map((d) => {
 return d.b
});
const c = data.map((d) => {
 return d.c
});
```